# How to apply pigeonhole principle to this problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $S$ be any set, How large does $S$ need to be to guarantee that any function $f:S\to [100]=\{1,2,\cdots,100\}$ has the property that there is some $i\in [100]$ that gets associated with $i$ elements of $S$?

Comment: Request that ambiguity be resolved: "... that gets associated with $i$ elements of $S$.  Do you intend **exactly** $i$ or at least $i$?  If the latter, then the answer of RobertTheTutor pertains.  If the former, then his answer does **not** resolve your query.  Which is it?

Comment: it should be exactly i elements, can you further explain the answer of RobertTheTutor? How does he apply the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: Imagine that instead of [100], you are working with [5].  Further imagine that you had answered my request for clarification by : "*at least* $(i)$", instead of exactly $i$.  Then you couldn't have any elements map to $1$, only $1$ element map to $2$, $\cdots$, only $4$ elements map to $5$.  Therefore, working with $[5]$ instead of $[100]$, the answer would have been $S$ needs to have at least $(1 + \sum_{k=0}^4 k = 11)$ elements.  ...see next comment.

Comment: If you had given the answer of *at least $(i)$*, then the pigeonhole principle would readily apply.  However, **instead** you answered **exactly** $(i)$ which means that RobertTheTutor's response does not resolve your query.  **Are you sure** about your response?  Are you sure that the constraint is that you can't have an element $(i)$ such that **exactly** $(i)$ elements map to $(i)$.  If you are sure, then I think that the query has no answer.  That is, you could have 100 million elements in $S$, with 1 million of them mapping to each value of $i$.

Comment: I kinda get it, you are using strong pigeonhole principle, which is let $q_{1},q_{2},\cdots,q_{n}$ be non-negative integer, if $1-n + \sum_{i=1}^{n} q_{i}$ objects are distributed into $n$ boxes , then there exists some i such that box i has at least $q_{i}$ objects. Is this what you saying?

Comment: No, let me use different words.  Based on the constraint of *at least* $(i)$, imagine that the most elements that can be mapped to the element $(i)$ is $(i-1)$.  Then, the most elements that can be mapped to each of $\{1,2,3, \cdots, 100\}$ is $\{0,1,2, \cdots, 99\}$, respectively.  Note that $\sum_{k=0}^{99} k = (4950).$  Thus, if $S$ has at least $(4951)$ elements, the mapping of element number $(4951)$ will necessarily **overfill** one of elements in the range of $f$, which is $\{1,2,3,\cdots,100\}.$

Comment: Ah, i see what you mean, thank you

Answer (score 1):

For the case where there must be exactly $i$ elements that map to $i$, there is no maximum, because you can simply have a million elements (or an arbitrarily large number) map to each.

For the case where there must be at least $I$ elements that map to $I$, the simplest way to think of these problems is to imagine avoiding the outcome for as long as possible. You can't have 1 element map to 1, so that's zero.  You can't have 2 elements map to 2, so you have at most 1 of those.  You can't have 3 elements map to 3, so that's 2 elements, and so on.  So you can have $$\sum_{0}^{99} i = 99(100)/2 = 4950 $$ without satisfying the condition, and your answer is $4951$.

Comment: See my comment/request to the OP for clarification.  Based on his response to my query, I question whether your answer pertains.

Comment: Thank you. I have amended my solution.